# Is there a toBool function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a function/method to evaluate whether a value evaluates to `true` or `false` in javascript? If not, is the following a good substitute?

```
const toBool = (x) => x ? true : false;
```

Comment: There isn't one because it isn't necessary - just use JS's falsyness naturally (or the `!!x` idiom). How does this `toBool` function improve JS programs at all? It doesn't make them any more readable nor more maintainable - this adds zero value, in my opinion.

Comment: @Dai There is use cases for this, but I agree if you're just planning on using it like: `if (toBool(x))` it doesn't make sense, but there are cases where you need a true/false rather than truthy value.

Comment: Couple ways: `Boolean(x)` will convert to boolean (be sure not to use new). So will `!!x`. Note that as the other comment suggests it is rarely necessary to do this. Unless we're talking about Typescript.

Comment: @JaredSmith TypeScript supports `!!x` though - and using `Boolean(x)` as you suggest is also equivalent to this `toBool` though.

Comment: @dai meant more that unlike JS, TS actually cares about whether something is boolean or just truthy/falsey

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary is fine. An alternative is `const toBool = (x) => !!x;`